# Mi trigger no me deja agregar registros

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, trigger

Tengo un trigger para que cuando las condicones se cumplan me tire un error pero aun cuando estas no se cumplen no puedo realizar ningun registro

```
ALTER trigger [dbo].[Filtro_Hora_Reserva] on [dbo].[tblReserva]
    after insert as 
declare @count int = 1
while (@count < (select MAX(idReserva) from tblReserva) + 1) 
begin
    if (((select idHoraIn from tblReserva where idReserva = @count) = (select idHoraIn from inserted) 
    and
    (select idCurso from tblReserva where idReserva = @count) = (select idCurso from inserted)
    and
    (select idDias from tblReserva where idReserva = @count) = (select idDias from inserted)
    and
    (select idSemana from tblReserva where idReserva = @count) = (select idSemana from inserted))
    or
    ((select idHoraIn from tblClase where idClase = @count) = (select idHoraIn from inserted) 
    and
    (select idCurso from tblClase where idClase = @count) = (select idCurso from inserted)
    and
    (select idDias from tblClase where idClase = @count) = (select idDias from inserted)))
    begin
        raiserror ('Hora_Reserva', 16, 1)
        rollback
    end
    set @count = @count + 1
end
```

Comment: Pregunta: Deberias de agregar top 1 a tus selects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta evitar, dentro de lo posible los bucles en TSQL. Además para evitar la inserción de valores duplicados en la tabla registro puedes crear una restricción unique.

```
Create table tblReserva
             (
             idReserva int
           , idHorain  int
           , idCurso   int
           , idDias    int
           , idSemana  int
             );

Create table tblClase
             (
             idClase  int
           , idHoraIn int
           , idCurso  int
           , idDias   int
             );
go
```

Con las tablas ya creadas:

```
Alter table dbo.TblReserva 
Add constraint uq_tblReserva unique (idHorain, idCurso, idDias, idSemana);
go
```

Generamos la restricción [unique](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-unique-constraints?view=sql-server-ver15) para las columnas mencionadas.

Dentro del trigger para la otra tabla y como ejemplo puedes utilizar exists, pues el operador funciona independientemente de que inserten una fila o n filas.

```
create or alter trigger tr_Filtro_Hora_Reserva on dbo.tblReserva
after insert
as

    if exists (
        select *
           from inserted AS i
        where exists (
              select *
                 from tblClase AS t
                     where isnull(t.idHorain,0) = i.idHorain 
                       and isnull(t.idDias,0) = i.idDias 
                       and isnull(t.idCurso,0) = i.idCurso
                    )
              ) 
    begin
        raiserror('Hora_Clase', 16, 1);
        rollback tran;
    end;
go
```

Observa que la consulta interior hace referencia al mismo campo de la consulta exterior.
Si esa consulta devuelve registros, entonces se cumple el if exists()

Ejemplos de inserciones válidas.

```
Insert into dbo.tblReserva (idReserva, idHorain, idCurso, idDias, idSemana)
values
(1,1,1,1,1),
(2,1,2,1,1),
(3,1,1,2,1),
(4,1,1,1,2);
```

Ahora una inserción múltiple con error

```
Insert into dbo.tblReserva (idReserva, idHorain, idCurso, idDias, idSemana)
values
(5,3,1,1,1),
(6,2,1,1,1),
(7,1,2,1,1), -- esta no cumple porque el registro 2 ya tiene estos valores
(8,5,1,1,2);

Mens. 2627, Nivel 14, Estado 1, Línea 52
Infracción de la restricción UNIQUE KEY 'uq_tblReserva'. 
No se puede insertar una clave duplicada en el objeto 'dbo.tblReserva'. 
El valor de la clave duplicada es (1, 2, 1, 1).
Se terminó la instrucción.

Insert into tblClase (idClase, idHoraIn, idCurso, idDias)
values
(1,9,1,1);

Insert into dbo.tblReserva (idReserva, idHorain, idCurso, idDias, idSemana)
values
(5,3,1,1,1),
(6,2,1,1,1), -- esta no cumple porque clase tiene 9 en horaIn. Resto igual
(7,2,9,1,1), 
(8,5,1,1,2);

Mensaje 50000, nivel 16, estado 1, procedimiento tr_Filtro_Hora_Reserva, 
línea 15 [línea de inicio de lote 51]
Hora_Clase
Mens. 3609, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Línea 52
La transacción terminó en el desencadenador. Se anuló el lote.
```

[Trigger after insert. Como hacerlos](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/04/12/trigger-que-es-como-se-hace-y-como-funciona-after-for-insert/)